# Ordering data frame by different factors

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe like this:

```
x <- data.frame("Group"= c(rep(letters[1],2),rep(letters[2],2),rep(letters[3],2),rep(letters[4],2),letters[5]) , "Treatment"=   c(rep(c("ATR","Co"),4),"Gen"), "Mean" = 1:9)
```

Want I want to do with it is order it in a custom way, namely move the rows of "Gen" Treatment to the first row. I could find them with something like:

```
if( "Genetic Control", idGroup$Treatment)
match("Genetic Control",idGroup$Treatment)
if(grepl("Gen",x$Treatment...
```

But I couldn´t find any function that moves the row above to the first row.
Once I manage this, I want to order the rest of the data by the mean of x$mean of the two components of each group. For instance, in this case the mean of the two components of "d" is 7.5 and so it will go in the following rows after "Gen" treatment. In this example the dataframe should look like this:

```
  x <- data.frame("Group"= c(letters[5], rep(letters[4],2),rep(letters[3],2),rep(letters[2],2),rep(letters[1],2)), "Treatment"=   c("Gen", rep(c("ATR","Co"),4)), "Mean" = 9:1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated answer using the R package [sqldf](http://www.r-bloggers.com/manipulating-data-frames-using-sqldf-a-brief-overview/) (click link for a brief intro).

```
library(sqldf)

x <- data.frame(
        "Group"= c(rep(letters[1],2),rep(letters[2],2),rep(letters[3],2),rep(letters[4],2),letters[5]), 
        "Treatment"=   c(rep(c("ATR","Co"),4),"Gen"), 
        "Mean" = 1:9)
```

Firstly, you can get the mean of column `Mean` for each group with this statement (similar to `aggregate` in R):

```
sqldf("
SELECT 
    `Group` AS `Group`, 
    AVG(`Mean`) AS `GroupMean` 
FROM x 
GROUP BY `Group`;")

  Group GroupMean
1     a       1.5
2     b       3.5
3     c       5.5
4     d       7.5
5     e       9.0
```

Then it is a case of using the `JOIN` statement (like `merge` in R) to join this table to the original one, putting 'Gen' at the top and then sorting by `GroupMean`. I call these these tables `t1` and `t2`, join them together, and then select from them the columns I want, and sorting the table. I have formatted the query so hopefully it is easier to understand. It should help to read a couple of articles on `MySQL` or `sqldf`. Also, as per the comment by @G. Grothendieck, you can use ` to enclose column names and ' to enclose strings. Hope this helps.

```
sqldf("
SELECT 
    t1.`Group` AS `Group`, 
    t1.`Treatment` AS `Treatment`, 
    t1.`Mean` AS `Mean`, 
    t2.`GroupMean` AS `GroupMean` 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM x) t1
    JOIN
    (SELECT 
        `Group` AS `Group`, 
        AVG(`Mean`) AS `GroupMean` 
    FROM x 
    GROUP BY `Group`) t2
    ON t1.`Group` = t2.`Group`
ORDER BY CASE `Treatment` WHEN 'Gen' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
    `GroupMean` DESC, 
    `Mean` DESC;
")

  Group Treatment Mean GroupMean
1     e       Gen    9       9.0
2     d        Co    8       7.5
3     d       ATR    7       7.5
4     c        Co    6       5.5
5     c       ATR    5       5.5
6     b        Co    4       3.5
7     b       ATR    3       3.5
8     a        Co    2       1.5
9     a       ATR    1       1.5
```

Comment: If you put the word group in quotes it won't regard it as a keyword.

Comment: Could you please explain briefly how is it done, I mean what functions are doing what, I´m having some trouble to understand it so that I can apply it to my real data

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully it is clearer now. @G. Grothendieck thanks I updated my answer with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x$Treatment <- ordered(x$Treatment, levels = c("Gen", "ATR", "Co")) 
x <- x[order(x$Treatment), ]
```

Define the `levels` in the order you want them
Use `unique(x$Treatment)` to see the Treatments you have.

For the second part of your question i am not sure i understand. Try this and let me know if it works:

```
library(dplyr)

x$rank <- (x$Treatment!="Gen")*1
x <- x %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(temp=mean(Mean)) %>% 
      ungroup %>% arrange(rank, -temp) %>% select(-rank, -temp)
```